# Not using group by in second part of sum

Tags: sql

This is my sum clause

```
Select *,(sum(current_bal-curr_bal_now)/ 
current_bal from base
Group by month
```

This gives me an error because  I'm not using current_bal in the group by. 
Is there a way of not using group by current_bal aswell as month  as it completely messes up the output layout.

Thanks

Comment: No using an aggregate function on current_bal makes no sense in this query ... What do you actually try to achieve ?

Comment: Please specify RDBMS and provide example data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the minus clause

Comment: You still haven't told us what database system you are using. (e.g. SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?) or provided an example demonstrating your actual requirement.

Comment: sql server. I want the sum to be exactly that so I don't have to group by current_bal

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2000/2005/2008/2012? And please supply a few rows of example data along with the desired results for that data.

Comment: 2008. So there should be one row sept2012 along with many columns from base and then one column extra at the end which is the result of all the current_bal-curr_bal/ current_bal for all the rows which are in sep2012

Comment: Providing example data would be much clearer and less ambiguous than trying to explain it verbally.

Answer (score 1):

Another guess...

```
SELECT *,
       ( sum(current_bal) OVER (PARTITION BY month) ) / current_bal
FROM   base
```

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan - Nope. It is ANSI SQL. Supported by e.g. Oracle and Postgesql too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sum will return you only a value, so, in your all select, `Current_bal` is different. Which one should choose ?

If what you want is add every division, something like this:

```
Select sum(current_bal/current_bal)
from base
Group by month
```

will work